# How can I disable "Are you sure you want to leave this page" popups in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

Is there a way to disable the *Are you sure you want to leave this page?* message on a website?
I'm using Chrome.

Comment: as @Vidar has mentioned, devs do this in webpages, and it should be considered a bad practice!  When I click on the 'x' to close my tab, I want it to close!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those messages are implemented by website developers by listening to the `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` events.

There is a [userscript available from about.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919231349/http://javascript.about.com/library/exitblock.user.js) that blocks those events.

In order to install this userscript (or other userscripts, for that sake) you need to first install a Chrome [extension called TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

Be careful when installing userscripts, they are capable of doing things you might not want. Only install userscripts from trusted sources.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).off('beforeunload.windowReload');
```

This is worked for me.

Comment: A bit more detail on your proposed solution would help

Comment: poor description. typed this in console but no result. don't work for me.

Comment: Downvoted for jQuery-specific solution without context.

Comment: This is SuperUser, the users are not expected to be programmers and to understand how to implement this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery

```
$(window).off('beforeunload'); // tested in IE 11 and Chrome 62
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names.

So in summation the `$(window)` gives us a reference to the window object that is wrapped in a jQuery object. This wrapper gives us access to jQuery APIs that are available on the object (such as `.off`). Calling `.off()` and providing the string `beforeunload` will remove any event listeners that were previously listening for the `beforeunload` event.

Note: I did play with the vanilla JS approaches I found after some quick research on Google. However, I was not able to get these approaches to work in the allotted time I had to resolve this issue. If someone has a non jQuery method that is still cross browser compatible please comment or post an additional answer. :)

Comment: I was unsuccessful using the accepted answer, and jQuery was already available on the page.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you would explain how to use it, and, ideally, something about how it works.

Comment: This is SuperUser, not Stack Overflow. Users aren't expected to know how to implement this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative, manual way to remove `beforeunload` event listeners:

0. Right click your web page in Chrome and choose Inspect from the menu, or type `Ctrl+Shift+I`.
1. Make sure you are in the Elements tab and that the right side panel is visible, if it isn't make sure the Inspect window is wide enough.
2. On the right side panel pick the "Event Listeners" tab.
3. Locate the `beforeunload` event listener in the list and expand it
4. Use the "Remove" button for all the event listeners under it.

[image: visual instructions]

---

And a vanilla-JS way that doesn't require jQuery. Thanks to [Mike Sraj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61258158/9205341):

```
function removeListenersFromElement(element, listenerType){
    const listeners = getEventListeners(element)[listenerType];
    let l = listeners.length;
    for(let i = l-1; i >=0; i--) {
        removeEventListener(listenerType, listeners[i].listener);
    }
}
removeListenersFromElement(window, "beforeunload");
```

Answer (score 0):

so to get the command from @wickdninja working, first install Chrome Developer Tools. Then you can open that and you will see a tab for 'Console'. Click the Console tab. Then to enable jQuery type these commands:

```
var jqry = document.createElement('script');
jqry.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqry);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then type:

```
$(window).off('beforeunload');
```

after that i am able to open/close my gmail without getting the 'Leave?' prompt.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/javascript

hope this helps.

Comment: That solutions don't work. 
Also I don't understand how to "install Chrome Developer Tools". Chrome Developer Tool is a part of Chrome Browser already. There is no way to install/uninstall it.

Answer (score -5):

You can disable Javascript on a site-by-site basis. Go to Settings --> Show advanced settings --> Privacy --> Content settings --> Javascript --> Manage exceptions.

Comment: Yes, but that will disable more than just the message.

Comment: In FIrefox at least, disallowing facebook to run javascript doesn't even accomplish what the OP intends as the page simply keeps reloading the script without executing it.